# How to get java heap stats in unix for weblogic managed servers

Tags: java, weblogic11g, health-monitoring

How do we get the Java heap, memory stats and other health monitoring statistics from a Unix machine instead of from the weblogic console.

Comment: Can some one help me with this

Comment: Use `top` or use `jConsole` and connect to the server process. This question does not really belong here as it's a basic Unix question, not a programming question

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to get memory information based on the weblogic server process id.  If you use

```
ps -ef | grep |insert weblogic server name|
```

to get the process ID of the weblogic server in question you can then use [this document](http://www.unixlore.net/articles/quick-easy-way-monitor-process-memory-usage.html) to get the memory usage of that process.